# Get page content from page-title

Tags: 7

Is it possible to get page content (in array) from for example a Title. Like this;

```
$wantedPage = function_to_get_page_content('This is the title');
```

and then just `print_r($wantedPage)` to get this page content, in array.

I'm pretty new on this great CMS-system..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you mean is the node contents, in D6, this would be as easy as `$node = node_load(array('title' => $text));` and I would hope the same holds true it D7, but I've been known to misspeak a bit there :)  Just realize that titles aren't necessarily unique.  If you mean the page, with all the header, footer, css, js, blocks and so forth, that's another story in of itself.

Comment: Well, I know that would be a problem, but is it possible to also add the content-type in some how, because Swans has the content-type "subfamily" and Mute Swan has the "specie" content-type?

Comment: `node_load(array('title' => $text, 'type' => $type));`

Comment: Found the solution... 
 `$items = entity_load('node', FALSE, array('type' => 'mytype', 'title' => $text));` is the right in D7.